# machine learning (unsupervised method)

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have a question about Reinforcement learning. If we use a mechanism to find the response of the environment in an unsupervised method to improve its performance, is the method still unsupervised?

In other word, using the response of the environment, is a method supervised or we can do it in an unsupervised manner? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

I have to disagree with @phs. Reinforcment learning is treated in the literature either as:

- completely separate, third method of training -- so it is not supervised or unsupervised, it is simply reinforcment
- it is sometimes marked as supervised due to its much stronger similarities to this paradigm

So, if the algorithm is trained in the reinforcment fashion and unsupervised, you can call it a unsupervised-reinforcment hybrid or something similar, but no longer "unsupervised", as reinforcment learning requires some additional knowledge about the world, than the one encoded in the data representation (feedbacks are not stored in data representation, they are much more like "true labels").

Comment: This is especially true in the (relatively common) case where reinforcement learning is being used to develop a policy for behavior in the future, with the intention of turning off learning after an acceptable policy has been found.

Answer (score 0):

Unsupervised learning describes a class of problems where the model is not provided "answers" during its training phase, whatever that might mean in the current context.

Clustering is a canonical example.  In a clustering problem one is only looking for inherent structure or grouping in the training data, and not seeking to distinguish "right" data points from "wrong" ones.

Your question is vague, but I believe you are asking whether we can call a training method unsupervised even if we have a proscribed algorithm for performing the training.  The answer is yes; the word is just a word.  All learning algorithms have inherent proscribed structure (the algorithm) and so are in some sense "supervised".